# Why doesn't my data source appear in data source tab in visual studio?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

My solution is setup with a main Application project and a DAL project for the data. I created a DataSet in the DAL project and then in my Application project WPF window I want to use that Datasource but it doesn't appear in the Data Source Tab.

I have the DAL project set as a dependency of the Application project.

Any ideas? VS 2015 Enterprise

Comment: Aren't DataSets a bit *oldish*?

Comment: Yes. And apparently they suck. Switching to Entity framework.